# Whats is the HTML Code If put some entry in Text Box then click button and I receive result Text Entry with my URL (Like URL+Text)

Tags: php, html

Example

http://www.example.com (URL) + 72923773927 (Text)

I put only (Text) entry in text box and click button then I need to result my browser redirect new url like below

http://www.example.com/72923773927

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="get" target="_blank">
  Your Text: <input type="text" name="text"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

use **GET** method